# Sum of all solutions of equation $\sin{2x} = 1 + \sqrt{2}\cos{x} + \cos{2x}$ on interval $(0,2\pi)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Solution of this task is ${7\pi\over2}$ but I don't know how to get to this solution.I used the formula for double angle for $\sin{2x}$ and $\cos{2x}$ and moved everything on one side of the equation and made $2\cos{x}$ as common factor to get this :$$2\cos{x}(\sin{x} - {\sqrt{2}\over2} - \cos{x}) = 0$$
Then I can get that $\cos{x} = 0$ and that solution for this particular x are $x = {\pi\over2}$ and $x = {3\pi\over2}$. But I don't know what to do next inside these brackets to get the rest.

EDIT: So I get at the end that $\sin{2x} = {1\over2}$ but solutions I get then are: 
$$\sin{2x} = {1\over 2}$$
$$2x = {\pi\over6} \quad \text{&}\quad 2x = {5\pi\over6}$$
$$x = {\pi\over12} \quad \text{&}\quad x = {5\pi\over12}$$
And when then I sum up those two with already found:
$${\pi\over2}+{3\pi\over2} + {\pi\over12}+{5\pi\over12}=$$
$$={6\pi\over12}+{18\pi\over12} + {\pi\over12}+{5\pi\over12}=$$
$$={30\pi\over12}={5\pi\over2}$$
Which is not the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:$$\sin x - \cos x = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \Rightarrow \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}$$. Can you continue ?

Comment: Nope, I do not see the reasoning behind this.I mean I don't what I should use to get this?

Comment: $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)), so $\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sin x\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin \frac{\pi}{4}\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\sin x-\cos x \right)$.

Comment: When I use this process I get the sum above ${7\pi}\over2$, while I do as @hkmather802 did I get less than ${7\pi}\over2$. Unfortunately, that is not what is written in solutions

Answer (score 1):

$$(2\sin x-\sqrt{2}-2\cos x)=0$$
$$(2\sin x-2\cos x)=\sqrt{2}$$
$$4\sin^2 x-8\sin x \cos x+4\cos^2 x=2$$
$$4-8\sin x \cos x=2$$
$$\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$0.5\sin 2x=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\sin 2x=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

see the graph of function.

But I think there is a problem in your answer which is $\frac{7\pi}{2}$ because it is not within the given interval.

[image]

Comment: Can you just look at my edit and see what is the problem?

Comment: @GreatDuke see the edit in my answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin{x} - {\sqrt{2}\over2} - \cos{x} = 0$$
$$\sin x-\cos x=\frac{\sqrt2} 2$$
$$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=\frac12$$
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\sin x\cos x=\frac12$$
$$1-\sin 2x=\frac12$$
$$\sin 2x=\frac12$$

Comment: You'll have to check the solutions on the initial equation (or see if $\sin x-\cos x>0$) after this because squaring both sides can introduce extraneous solutions. KfSsOc's approach is better, since so checking is needed when solutions are found.